# jQuery Mobile NOT Inset Collapsible Section

Tags: jquery-mobile

Working with the jQuery mobile frame work.  [The documents](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html) state that if you add `data-inset="false"` to  `data-role="copllapsible"` the collapsible element will take the full screen width (and indeed the example on the docs page does).

When I try it in my application it fails, and is always rendered as an "inset" element.

#### Markup:

```
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
    <li>
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-inset="false">
        <h4>
          Pad Thai
        </h4>
        <ul data-role="listview">
          <li>
            rice
          </li>
          <li>
            peanuts
          </li>
          <li>
            spicey stuff
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      Pork
    </li>
    <li>
      Beans
    </li>
  </ul>
```

What can I do to get the expected, non-inset rendering?

(I started a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/soodesune/m8BBd/3/))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but perhaps collapsible lists can help?  See http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html